# How to set Delay time in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to set delay time for my jquery code? I try somthing like below.

This is the HTML markup:

```
<div class="fleft process" id="fade1" >
    <div class="dot-circle row m0">
        <div class="icon-circle row m0">
            <img src="img/people.png" alt="people" >
                <div class="row m0 hover-text">
                Smart Ideas<br>Steady Growth
                </div>
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row m0">1. People</div>
```

This is CSS:

```
#fade1 {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;  
}

#fade1.on {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This is the jQuery code:

```
$(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 2300)
      $("#fade1").delay(3000).addClass('on');
    else
      $("#fade1").removeClass('on');
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't see where you are trying to delay anything ...

Comment: actually i don't know where to use delay function.

Comment: then describe a bit more what are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you want to delay the addition of the css class. You could try javascript's **setTimeout()** method :

```
$(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 2300){
      setTimeout($("#fade1").addClass('on'), 3000);
    } else {
      setTimeout($("#fade1").removeClass('on'), 3000);  
    } 
});
});
```

Comment: It would help if you told us what you are trying to achieve as @the-noob said.

Comment: I want to set delay time for addClass(on).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use [Javascript setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) Method?

```
$(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 2300){
      setTimeout(function(){
          $("#fade1").addClass('on');
      }, 3000);
    }else{
      $("#fade1").removeClass('on');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: If your `$(window).scroll` and `if else` statements are working correctly, it should work!

Comment: Glad to know that :) Happy Coding!